# Injecting urls taking too long

Tags: nutch, inject

I have configured Hbase 0.94.14 and Nutch 2.3 through [this](https://gist.github.com/xrstf/b48a970098a8e76943b9) tutorial and made a seed directory which contains a text file with the urls. When I want to inject these urls using this command:

```
$NUTCH_ROOT/runtime/local/bin/nutch inject /seed
```

I get the following output:

```
InjectorJob: starting at 2015-07-23 14:00:24

InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: /seed
```

and stays in this state forever.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Answer (score -2):

Your Nutch version is 2.3. You should not run the command line in `$NUTCH_ROOT/runtime/local/bin/nutch`, you should run the command in `$NUTCH_ROOT/runtime/deploy/bin/nutch` instead.

Hope this helps,

Le Quoc Do